# paste/concatenate string involving backslash

Tags: r

I have a function which accepts the argument `bm` (which is then passed to `format()`). At some point in the function, I would like to use the same argument `bm` and paste it to an element of a vector. As you can see from the minimal example, the strings are not the same. How can I (given the argument `bm`) use the argument `bm` and some sort of `paste()`... to get the same result as `format()` (namely `\\,` instead of `\\\\,`)?

```
bm <- "\\\\,"
x <- format(c(1,10000), big.mark=bm, trim=TRUE)
y <- x
y[1] <- paste0(bm, x[1])
y # both components should contain \\,
```

Comment: Paste a version of `bm` without the first \...?

Comment: This gives `Error: '\,' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "\\\,"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps you but `\\\\,1` has length 4 and `10\\,000` has length 7.  I assume you wanted y[2] equal to R string `10\\\\,000`.  One way of doing this is to use `encodeString()` after you manipulate your string:

```
bm <- "\\\\," 
x <- encodeString(format(c(1,10000), big.mark=bm, trim=TRUE))
y <- x
y[1] <- paste0(bm, x[1])
y
# [1] "\\\\,1"     "10\\\\,000"
```